# How to add empty map<string,string> type column to DataFrame in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried below code but its not working:

```
df=df.withColumn("cars", typedLit(Map.empty[String, String]))
```

Gives the error: `NameError: name 'typedLit' is not defined`

Comment: was that imported before using?

Comment: @samkart no, I am unable to what to import for this

Comment: I just saw the tags -- pyspark does not have `typedLit`, but similar can be achieved using `array` and `lit` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62115150/8279585)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty column and cast it to the type you need.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

df = df.withColumn("cars", F.lit(None).cast(T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
```

```
df.select("cars").printSchema()
root
 |-- cars: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df.withColumn("cars",expr("map()")).printSchema()                                                                                                       
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cars: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
```

EDIT:

If you'd like your map to have keys and/or values of a non-trivial type (not map<string,string> as your question's title says), some casting becomes unavoidable, I'm afraid. For example:

```
>>> df.withColumn("cars",create_map(lit(None).cast(IntegerType()),lit(None).cast(DoubleType()))).printSchema()                                      
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cars: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
```

...in addition to other options suggested by @blackbishop and @Steven.
And just beware of the consequences :) -- maps can't have `null` keys!

Comment: Thanks you, One more question, what if i want to create map<int,int> ?

Comment: @RahulDiggi use my solution for that !

Comment: Or `expr("cast(map() as map<int,int>)")`..

Comment: @blackbishop I wonder if that would work? The typecast looks a bit unsafe!

Comment: @mazaneicha It should :) Note the difference: `cast(map() as map<int,int>)` creates an **empty map** whereas in the other solution it creates a **NULL value** of type map (it's equivalent to `cast(null as map<int,int>)`). Also, `create_map` function can't be used in this particular case as you can't pass null for keys.

Comment: @blackbishop Hmmm...  ```>>> df.withColumn("mapcol",expr("cast(map() as map<int,int>)")).show()                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ... raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'map()' due to ***data type mismatch: cannot cast map<string,string> to map<int,int>;*** ...```  The other option ```cast(null as ... )``` works fine, but thats basically what @Steven suggested.

Comment: @mazaneicha which version of spark are you using? I can execute the same code with spark 3.2, it works just fine.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I tried on 2.4.7.